# HTML email sent from Thunderbird doesn't show right in other email clients

Tags: thunderbird, webmail

I'm experimenting with HTML emails right now, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I initially tried from the GMail, but learned that I could not. I then tried with Hotmail, and that worked to a small extent (Options > Edit in HTML) but most of the formatting was missing (stripped, I assume, by Hotmail).

Then I tried using Thunderbird (Insert > HTML), and that worked... only in Thunderbird. If I opened the email in Thunderbird, then it would display right. If I opened it in Gmail or Hotmail, the aforementioned problems would occur.

I've seen problems with Gmail and sending HTML emails, but not Hotmail or Thunderbird.

Here are some images:

Normal:

[image: Normal]

Thunderbird: (normal)

[image: Thunderbird]

Hotmail: (some formatting missing)

[image: Hotmail]

Gmail: (plain text, all formatting missing)

[image: Gmail]

If you suspect the code might be problematic, [here it is](http://pastebin.com/E3MmTfj1).

Does anyone understand why? Please explain.

Comment: It seems to me that it's an issue with Thunderbird and, as such, is off-topic here. Installable software is on-topic at [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just searching around and I found that, according to this what-to-know-about-html-emails [link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-you-should-know-about-html-email--webdesign-12908) that HTML emails have no standards.

In this how-to [link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770), it describes some of the missing standards, such as `padding` for `div`s and `p`s but the support for `table`s. It also recommended to use HTML attributes whenever possible because of the sporadically-supported CSS.

This was my problem: I used some unsupported CSS.

I hope this helps someone!